# Is there a single word "synonym" for "synonym"?

Tags: single-word-requests

It appears that there is not a single word that is the equivalent word for "synonym" in general usage. Is this the case?

Comment: 'that word is a [doppleganger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppelgänger) for this one'

Comment: [Thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/synonym) has *equivalent,* which is probably in general use. What did you look up and find out?

Comment: I am sorry that I didn't find that this question had already been asked. I am new to this site. I searched for "synonym for synonym" but I am pretty the duplicate didn't come up. I had, of course, checked other web sources but I was hoping for an authoritative answer.